# python concurrency for instances of same class using Object Oriented methods

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

I want two objects of the same class to operate concurrently. The class "MyClass" has a function that connects an instance to another instance of the class. I also need to keep track of the objects that have been created (oList). what I am trying is:

main.py:

```
from MyClass import MyClass
import time

oList = []

class oCreator1(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.o1 = MyClass()

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            time.sleep(1)
            print "Hi"

    def getO1(self):
        return self.o1

class oCreator2(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.o2 = MyClass()

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            time.sleep(1)
            print "Bye!"

    def getO2(self):
        return self.o2

main():

    threadList = []
    global oList

    oc1 = oCreator1()
    threadList.append(oc1)
    o1 = oc1.getO1()
    oList.append(o1)

    oc2 = oCreator2()
    threadList.append(oc2)
    o2 = oc2.getO2()
    oList.append(o2)

    o1.connToAnotherO(o2)

    print oList

    for t in threadList:
        t.start()
        t.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But the only thing that is printed is "Hi". I really want to know the things I'm doing wrong and the right way to do it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: its too long. really really long! o_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for t in threadList:
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

The `t.join()` call waits for the thread `t` to finish. That means when you start the first thread, you wait for it to finish before starting the second, but the first thread is just going to keep printing `Hi` forever. It'll never finish.

Don't `join`, or don't start `join`ing until all threads have started.